# Rendering DirectX 3D graphics onto an Image directly, using C#

Tags: c#, image, directx, rendering

The project I'm working on requires the ability to transform any of the 4 corners of an image.  As GDI+ unfortunately doesn't have this capability, we're resorting into using DirectX's 3D graphics.

While I have a square mesh with a texture showing successfully on-screen, I need to be able to generate an image from this rendering, with the background set to transparent.  Is there a way to efficiently achieve this?

Preferably, I'd like to do this without using a Control for initializing a device. Alternatively, I don't mind the option of creating a custom, invisible Control that will generates an image for me.

**Edit**:

Actually, I just realized a transparent background is strictly not necessary, but it would help the performance of our project a bit.

Anyway, I've had some luck doing something like this, but it is excessively slow. Perhaps there's a better method?

```
// Create a surface to render an image to
Surface mSurface = mDevice.GetRenderTarget(0);

// Render the visualization
mDevice.Clear(ClearFlags.Target, Color.Transparent, 1.0f, 0);
mDevice.BeginScene();

/* Do some amazing stuff */

// Exit rendering
mDevice.EndScene();
mDevice.Present();

// Render the bitmap images
GraphicsStream mGraphics = SurfaceLoader.SaveToStream(
        ImageFileFormat.Bmp, mSurface);
Image mImage = new Bitmap(mGraphics, false);
```

Comment: I noticed the Surface constructor takes in a Bitmap.  If I constructed a Surface with a Bitmap in memory, would rendering to this Surface update the held Bitmap as well?

Comment: I was wondering if constructing a Surface and a Bitmap with the same Stream information would work, too...

Answer (score 0):

Well if you use D3D for doing the final rendering to screen then you can easily do the things you are talking about using render-to-texture.

Comment: I'll try looking into it, but if you don't mind, could you provide a few examples?